# R: How to find means of columns greater than 1 after grouping by gender?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart, reshape2

How do I group the below sample of data by Gender and compute means for each of the genre columns within these groups considering only those values greater than 1? Ultimately I want to plot a bar chart with genres on the horizontal independent to each other, each characterized by two bars corresponding to each gender classification.

### Action |Adventure |Animation |Children| Comedy    | Gender

### 0    |     5    |     0    |    0   |   0       |     M

### 0    |     0    |     1    |    2   |   3       |     M

### 2    |     3    |     0    |    0   |   4       |     F

### 0    |     0    |     0    |    2   |   0       |     M

### 4    |     0    |     3    |    0   |   2       |     F

### 4    |     4    |     0    |    0   |   0       |     F

I'm aware of varipus possible ways of going about this problem but am looking for a compact code that can be executed in ggplot or other plot functions directly rather than having to do pre-processing the data and then using these to plotting. However, any smart approach is welcomed.

Comment: Perhaps you can share some of these various ways, and why they don't suit you. Also, please share the data in a form that people can actually get into their sessions (using `dput`, or at least not a ton of separators in all direction).

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -Gender) %>%
  filter(value > 1) %>%
  group_by(Gender, key) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(key, value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Gender), 
           position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: may be you should have also included the data, just to make the rest things reproducible by others. :-)